# Using an RC delay circuit on a MOSFET Gate

Tags: mosfet, bjt, comparator, discharge, charge

I have 24v Input from push button, I want to make delay when I leave the button and the PMOS will stay on for about 0.6sec.
Attaching some timing diagram for the required operation signals (pay attention, when 24v goes to zero means it's disconnected,someone release the button):
[image]

- input:meaning the button was pressed, the voltage will be 24v or open
- I want that black box will charge fast(0-40ms)
- when I release the button, I want the black box hold the voltage for about 0.6sec and the output will stay high means that PMOS will stay ON.
  I saw some idea about this circuit to use some Comparator(e.g. the blackbox will be comparator)([question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/661531/using-an-rc-delay-circuit-on-an-npn-bjt-base)):

[image]

but I have a couple of issues with this circuit:

- I want another discharge time (maybe some diode with another discharge route?)
- the SOURCE of my PMOS should be 24V, so the margin will be very narrow
- the current PMOS should drive will be about 3Amp
- I want that will be in architecture High-Side Switch so that why I chose PMOS
- It's okay to use some voltage divider before the comparator (voltage divider to push-button) but I need to switch 24V to another stage 24v_FET.

Should I use another BJT after the comparator?
Should I use comparator at all?
I have another 3.3v in my circuit from another supply, so can I use it if you see some need.

Comment: You should make sure you are using your MOSFET either fully turned on or fully turned off. Otherwise it will have to dissipate a lot when held in between. If you use an RC filter to drive the gate of the MOSFET, you will do exactly that.

Comment: @Blup1980 so how do I ensure it ?

Comment: You should use a negative edge triggered retriggerable monostable

Comment: @Andyaka which one? 555?

Comment: I'd never use a 555 so I can't recommend it. Id use this: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2051431.pdf